# dropzone.js sends empty $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload, dropzone.js

I try to use [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to make a drag-and-drop file upload area and I'm getting really desperate here. I have this simplest script:

```
<?php
  print_r($_FILES);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
            <input name="file" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="dropzone.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I manually select the file using the file input button, I get this result:

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => test.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php4DFF.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 247 ) )
```

However, when I use dropzone drag-and-drop, the file appears as uploaded, but after submitting I get this:

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )
```

Also known as **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE** *Value: 4; No file was uploaded.*

Am I missing something here?

I tried to play with settings like *autoProcessQueue: false*, *autoDiscover: false*, automatic form submission, different scripts, different servers (apache/nginx), but absolutely nothing seems to work for me. There got to be some stupid thing that I'm just overseeing right now.

I use dropzone.js v4.0.1 but I tried older versions as well.

Comment: Are you aware of Ravishanker Kusuma's [jQuery Upload File Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php). I wouldn't muddy the water by introducing a different plugin if I didn't think it was a reliable solution. I use it all the time myself, think it's amazing. Also, the author monitors comments on his Disqus thread and assists daily. *Supports drag and drop "out of the box".* There are examples on his site, also many additional examples here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be submitting (hitting the submit button) with drop zone, it works asynchronously so once you drop the file in, it is hitting your php upload script without a need to do anything else. 
Once you hit submit it will be a second time, you are resubmitting the form and it will show up empty.

You should probably have your php on a separate page, as well, instead of submitting to itself. You will not be able to view this post in a browser after you submit it because it is ajax and async, but you can use chrome's dev tools to view the post at least.

Comment: I'm not finding any evidence that it's doing it for me, here, with 5.4.0.  Shouldn't something at least be showing up in the XHR tab in Developer Tools?

Comment: All the traffic is visible in the Network tab in chromium dev tools. Really helpful! Saved me another load of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

Same happend to me, when my file was larger than the configurated maximum (*upload_max_filesize*) in my php.ini file.

Other settings you might want to check:

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size
- max_input_time
- max_execution_time